# module.exports function is not defined after require from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello guys I'm starting in nodejs and I thought I understood how module.exports works but when using the same function in another file after requiring and using it in the index.js starter file I'm getting that first is not a function. I saw few similar answers but with more complex code and I didn't get the point that's why I'm asking it here so simple. Let me explain in more detail and sorry if it's too basic.

I run npm start and starts at the index.js file

Index.js

```js
const { first } = require("./first");

first();
```

First.js

```js
const { second } = require("./second");

function first(){
    
    return second();
}

module.exports = {
    first
}
```

Second.js

```js
const { first } = require("./first");

function second(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>resolve(), 1500)
    })
    .then(()=> {
        first()
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Here's the first is not a function
        console.log("Error here!!: ", err)
    })
}

module.exports = {
    second
}
```

The error is thrown in the catch of the second.js file. It says: Error here!!:  TypeError: first is not a function

Comment: What exactly is the error, and where is it thrown?

Comment: Welcome Alex! It would be helpful to know the error you're getting. Can you post the error as part of the question, so we know the exact error, and where it's being thrown. The more info the better.

Comment: The error is thrown in the catch of the second.js file. It says: Error here!!:  TypeError: first is not a function

Comment: why are you doing a circular reference?

Comment: Because I want to execute the first function again until a certain condition based from the second.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

> index.js

```
const  first  = require("./first");

first.first();
```

> first.js

```
const  second  = require("./second");

module.exports.first=function(){
    /* logic or code */
    return second.second();
}
```

> second.js

```
const  first  = require("./first");

module.exports.second=function(){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>resolve(), 1500)
    })
    .then(()=> {
        first.first()
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Here's the first is not a function
        console.log("Error here!!: ", err)
    })
}
```

Comment: No. I get Unexpected token export. The export you are saying is from react not valid for nodejs backend

Comment: @alex sorry for inconvenience I have edited my code please check it

Comment: Hello I make it worked based on your answer instead of calling first() in the second.js it should be first.first(). Please update it so I can validate it after. THnks

Answer (score 0):

This works to me, you need to add another anonnymus function in second.js.

`.then((good)=>{
   ()=>first()}).catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
}`

This is what you code should like.

```
function second(){
return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{res(),1500})})
    .then(()=>{()=>first()})
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})}
```